# Error in iterating/object arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, object

Good day, Im very confused why I keep on getting an undefined error whenever I tried to use '$x->split' when iterating through my array.

dd

```
$divs = array(3) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#247 (13) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(6)
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["transactionType"]=>
      string(4) "Bill"
      ["account_xid"]=>
      int(4)
      ["gt_xid"]=>
      int(1)
      ["u_xid"]=>
      int(2001)
      ["po_xid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["debit"]=>
      float(144)
      ["credit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["date_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-10-17 19:37:50"
      ["ref_no"]=>
      string(2) "22"
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["split"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#246 (1) {
          ["gt_xid"]=>
          int(1)
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#248 (12) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(6)
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["transactionType"]=>
      string(4) "Bill"
      ["account_xid"]=>
      int(4)
      ["gt_xid"]=>
      int(2)
      ["u_xid"]=>
      int(2001)
      ["po_xid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["debit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["credit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["date_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-11-15 01:40:00"
      ["ref_no"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["id"]=>
      int(4)
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#249 (13) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(6)
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["transactionType"]=>
      string(4) "Bill"
      ["account_xid"]=>
      int(4)
      ["gt_xid"]=>
      int(3)
      ["u_xid"]=>
      int(2001)
      ["po_xid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["debit"]=>
      float(2980)
      ["credit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["date_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-11-15 06:25:55"
      ["ref_no"]=>
      string(4) "0998"
      ["id"]=>
      int(6)
      ["split"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#254 (1) {
          ["gt_xid"]=>
          int(3)
        }
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#250 (13) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(6)
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["transactionType"]=>
      string(4) "Bill"
      ["account_xid"]=>
      int(4)
      ["gt_xid"]=>
      int(4)
      ["u_xid"]=>
      int(2001)
      ["po_xid"]=>
      int(0)
      ["debit"]=>
      float(500)
      ["credit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["date_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-11-15 06:37:07"
      ["ref_no"]=>
      NULL
      ["id"]=>
      int(8)
      ["split"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#256 (1) {
          ["gt_xid"]=>
          int(4)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["accountName"]=>
  string(15) "Inventory Asset"
  ["startingBalance"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

the thing is Im using that kind of format when I iterate through my array on my Items. here's the way I do it.

```
@foreach($divs as $div)
 {{ $div['accountNam'] }}
 @foreach($div['items'] as $x)
 {{ $x->description }}
 {{ $x->date_at }}
 {{ $x->transactionType }}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

that code above works fine but when I add the 3rd inner loop

```
 @foreach($divs as $div)
  {{ $div['accountNam'] }}
  @foreach($div['items'] as $x)
    {{ $x->description }}
    {{ $x->date_at }}
    {{ $x->transactionType }}
       @foreach($x->split as $z)
        ----I get error here---
       @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I get this error: Undefined property: stdClass::$split

when I tried to dd($z->split)

I get this result which means that its not empty or doesnt exist

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#246 (1) { ["gt_xid"]=> int(1) } }
```

Can You Please help me find the thing that I am missing here. To make it work. I already tried using $z['gt_xid'] but it gives me another error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array .. Thank you for spending time to read this. have a nice day ahead!

Comment: Why are you prepending each and every control structure with an `@`? This specifically tells PHP to *ignore* any possible errors and warnings generated there, thus making it a LOT harder for you to debug the code. Get rid of them and you'll have a much easier time debugging.

Comment: im using blade templating here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your array `$div['items']` is one element (index 1) without the `split` property.

if this may happen, you need to guard against it. I don't know the syntax you are using, but it will follow along these lines:

```
if (isset($x->split) :
  @foreach($x->split as $z)
    // do stuff
  @endforeach
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for that @cypherabe.. I did not realized it right away.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 2nd element (key 1) of your array doesn't have a "split" value.
You should test if "split" is defined (`isset($x->split)`) before trying to loop in it.